# Edit/Update the current lockscreen via batch? (Win 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, cmd.exe, regedit

So here's my question. I currently manage a group of Windows 10 machines, When I remote into them I have a custom lock screen that pops up saying "hey i'm remoted into this, don't mess with it"

Since the machines auto-login at boot, the only other time people see this screen is when they're booting up or shutting down.

The problem is recently something happened where they are being logged out or locked, and people weren't reporting it because they assumed I was remoted into it.

So I wanted to further evolve my lock screen so it only displays that message while I'm in the machine. I already open up a little batch script to rapidly do tasks while i'm in there, so If I could get it to change the lock screen when it opens up and change it back when I leave, that would be perfect.

I know you can change the wallpaper via a registry change, but I haven't found something similar for the Lock screen. My systems are Win 10 Pro.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the following group policy/registry key on the fly to see if it will change the lock screen? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d70ebe47-8681-4f21-813d-504b6cd071eb/group-policy-to-set-lock-screen-image-for-windows-10?forum=winserverGP

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  Before you answer that question, check out our help center, then reply to my question appropriately

Comment: Essentially, is there a way to live-update the lockscreen via batchscript in non-enterprise windows?